# Android Application not working after MobileFirst Upgrade

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I have upgraded my IBM MobileFirst server 6.3 to 7.1. The server has iOS, Android and Blackberry applications (environments) running.

After the upgrade of OS from Windows 2008 R2 to Windows 2012 R2 Datacenter and MobileFirst 7.1, all the applications are running fine except Android.

There is nothing in the logs on the server side, however, on the LogCat I saw below errors:

```
02-08 13:44:02.577: E/libEGL(4044): validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
02-08 13:44:03.271: E/AndroidProtocolHandler(4044): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/www/default/js/settings.js
02-08 13:44:32.323: E/NONE(4044): Uncaught Exception: Uncaught ReferenceError: pageinit is not defined at (compiled_code):599
```

Comment: You'll need to provide actual code.

Answer (score 0):

"settings.js" is not a MobileFirst-supplied file. It is also unclear from the supplied exception *where* in your code is the uncaught reference error.

Suggestions:

1. Remove the "native" folder and re-build the Android environment, or
2. Preview the Android environment in a browser (from the console), and check the Chrome DevTools console. See if the error happens there as well.

Right now nothing indicates a problem in MobileFirst, rather in the app.

Comment: Hi Idan,

Thanks for the reply, I didn't supplied the actual code, because the application was already running on 6.3 Server and is already in stores, the only thing which was changed is the server upgrade. 

If I rebuild the android environment, I will have to re-upload the application to the stores, which is not a preferred approach.

Comment: That may be your only solution, to upload an updated version. Please use your Test environment to re-build the project and see that the problem is resolved.

Comment: If you want to use 7.1, then 7.1.